# Convert string into real time date&time

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON code:

```
{ "time":"2015-10-20T11:20:00+02:00" }
```

I read that JSON from my script and the output in table is:

```
2015-10-20T11:20:00+02:00
```

However I want the output to be equal to that day and its time.

For example:  Tue 20:00 (if my timezone is +02)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can format dates like this:

```
var date = new Date('2015-10-20T11:20:00+02:00');
var days = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];
var output = days[date.getDay()] + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes();
console.log(output);
// Tue 6:20
```

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, the most clean way to deal with Date and Time is by using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). BTW, i will encourage to always store your datetime data in UTC and leave the local browser to show them in the local time zone.

To [format](http://momentjs.com/#format-dates) your input you could do the following:

```js
var vrijeme = "2015-10-20T11:20:00+02:00",
    date = moment(vrijeme, moment.ISO_8601);


var formatted = date.format('ddd h:mm');
console.log(formatted); // open the console with F12 to see the results
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In my experience storing as UTC works well when you store points in time (mostly in the past). For future dates it's often necessary to store the user-expected-time together with a time zone designation (like `Europe/Berlin`) since you can't convert reliably between that and UTC for future dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve without using days array

```js
function getTwoDigitValue(str) {
  return str.toString().length == 1 ? "0" + str : str;
}

(function() {
  var date = new Date('2015-10-20T11:20:00+02:00');
  var output = date.toString().split(" ")[0] + " " +
    getTwoDigitValue(date.getHours()) + ":" +
    getTwoDigitValue(date.getMinutes());

  console.log(output)
})()
```